# What happens if the length attribute is not specified on the @Column annontation for a String

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

What happen if I not specified the length attribute for following annotation?
Note that region is a String.

```
@Column(name = "REGION", nullable = false)
public String getRegion() {
        return region;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do not specify the `length` attribute then hibernate takes the default length which is `255` if the attribute type is `String`.

Check this [@Column.length](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/Column.html#length%28%29)

Answer (score 1):

The length attribute of the @Column annotation is only used during schema generation, viz:

```
@Column(name = "REGION", nullable = false, length=50)
public String getRegion() {
        return region;
    }
```

will create a column definition with length 50 if you are using your provider's schema generation functionality. If not, then it is of no relevance at all.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't use the length attribute nothing will happen default value is taken, exception will only be thrown when defined size in database side is exceeded i.e. `varchar2(32)` and entered value is more than that.

> But yes to restrict the size you can use `@Size(max=32)` to have
>   validation from code side.